# Anybody know of a free program to convert a .PPT to .AVI?

Tags: windows-xp, video, microsoft-powerpoint, encoding, avi

Anybody know of a free program to convert a .PPT to .AVI?

Preferably open source but anything that is free will work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Google is your friend!  I have not tried this.

[Powerpoint converter](http://www.effectmatrix.com/PowerPoint-Video-Converter/Free-PowerPoint-Video-Converter.htm)

\\Greg

Comment: Yeah, I saw some with google but was hoping for a recommendation from somebody that has actually used one and knows it is a quality program.


In any case, thanks for the google assistance.

Answer (score 3):

Try [Format Factory](http://www.formatoz.com/download.html)...It's freeware and the best one...